# How to Integrate RMSDK on IOS for DRM function

Tags: c++, iphone, adobe, lib, drm

I recently had trouble integrating RMSDK on IOS, can you give me some advice on DRM features?

Adobe provided me with a demo and an sdk zip file, I have successfully run the demo, but I don't know how to properly integrate RMSDK into my project.
I tried to cocopod the entire demo into a pod native library but failed,
Also try to create a new static library on the demo and try to put the c++ source files inside,
Export for reference But there are still a lot of errors (perhaps configuration and reference path configuration).
And those who have done it should know that the DRM function of the rmsdk needs to be used in conjunction with the certificate.
This allows me to verify whether my above two ideas are correct,

Because there is very little information about this on the Internet.
Is there someone who has done this before who can help me